# why would std::string s("??<") output a { instead of ??< as expected?

Tags: c++, encoding, string

```
std::string s("??<");
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Why does that output { instead of ??<

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  I'm assume it's encoding it but why and what is the encoding called if that is what's happening?

This little %#$^*! caused me to look for a bug in my (unit test) code for 30 minutes before I figured out my string was mangled!! :(

Comment: +1 This made me lol - but I knew the answer before I even got to the end of the question. :o

Comment: That's the kind of thing you get bugged by once and you never forget because of the time it takes for you to figure out what the problem is... my own discovery occured within a code block and it took me a while to understand why it failed to compile... it's fortunate that one can disable this wretched feature!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because of [trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs).

These are the supported trigraphs, from the Wikipedia page:

- `??=` → `#`
- `??/` → `\`
- `??'` → `^`
- `??(` → `[`
- `??)` → `]`
- `??!` → `|`
- `??<` → `{`
- `??>` → `}`
- `??-` → `~`

For Visual Studio, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462497%28VS.100%29.aspx) trigraphs are turned off by default (sensibly enough), so check your project/makefiles.

Comment: Never heard of those... nice!

Comment: Looks like ASP uses Digraphs too: `<%` -> `{`, `%>` -> `}`

Comment: Eh? ASP `<%` is part of its syntax, not a digraph in C/C++ sense. It's not "translated" to `{`. The major problem with C/C++ trigraphs is that they're replaced very early on, before the stream is even tokenized; thus, they're replaced in string literals, comments, etc...